# Keep showing unread mail notification in Gmail

Tags: notifications, gmail, android-11, notification-badges

Apparently, I'm one of the few people who use his mailbox as a to-do list, but since I got a new phone with Android 11, I lose my icon badge as soon as I clear the notification.

In the past, I could mark an email as unread, and then it would show an icon badge with how many unread emails I had. That way I could read as email and keep it unread as a to-do list. Marking another mail as unread would add a 1 to the icon.

Is there a setting I'm missing which would allow this? The only thing I find is people saying they get a notification even though they don't have mail.

Comment: The badge (also formally known as [the notification badge](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges) since Android 8.0) may depend on how the home screen and app implement it. Usually, it just shows current pending notifications though. Gmail app doesn't provide such customization, so the alternative is the home screen/another email app instead. Instead, you might also want to mention the previous device model/Android version/home screen app that behaves like what you described.

Comment: The previous device was a Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact (which I think had Android 8.0 but I'm not sure) and I just used the default mailing app since I used it for my gmail, hotmail, ... addresses. Now I'm using a Samsung Galaxy XCover 5. Do you know a homescreen/another email app which would do this?