# Badge icons disappear when clearing notification

Tags: notifications, notification-badges

I have a Samsung Galaxy S22. Overall I'm happy with it, but there is this one annoying feature. After I clear a notification, my badge icon which shows the nunber of unread emails for example disappears too. I'm using Nova Launcher Prime. But I think this is rather a Android / Samsung issue.

I've seen this asked in the past for older phones, but couldn't find any useful answers.

Can this be solved with a 3rd party app?

Comment: Possibly related/dupe of [Keep showing unread mail notification in Gmail](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246422/44325) (but not answered yet).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is because the notification counter reads directly from the notifications tray - even though in the app, you may have unread messages/notifications etc.
It's the way Android handles things in most cases. You can get an app that can log your notification history, to see if you've missed anything.
I've used Nova Launcher on lots of devices (Samsung,LG, Oneplus, Xiaomi) and they all behave this way. I cannot be 100% however, that ALL android phones do this.